# How to get the count of repeated value of some perticular attribute in array of object and store in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs

Suppose I have an array of Object.

code :

```
var arrayMap = [{continent: "Asia", Country: "China"},
{continent:"NAmerica", Country: "USA"},
{continent:"Asia", Country:"India"},
{continent:"Australia", Country:"Australia"},
{continent:"Asia", Country:"Japan"},
{continent:"Europe", Country:"UK"},
{continent:"SAmerica", Country:"Brazil"},
{continent:"Europe", Country:"Germany"},
{continent:"Asia", Country:"Rassia"},
{continent:"NAmerica", Country:"Canada"}]
```

Now I have two attribute continent and Country in arrayMap in Obj. I want to the counts of country in all continent. 
like :

```
 Obj{Asia: 4, NAmerica:2, Australia:1, Europe:2, SAmerica:1}
```

Can anybody help me how to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reduce method to get the count.Doc for reduce method. [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

reduce() method used for reduce element of array into single value.

Code Example :

```
    var arrayMap = [{continent: "Asia", Country: "China"},{continent:"NAmerica", Country: "USA"},{continent:"Asia", Country:"India"},{continent:"Australia", Country:"Australia"},{continent:"Asia", Country:"Japan"},{continent:"Europe", Country:"UK"},{continent:"SAmerica", Country:"Brazil"},{continent:"Europe", Country:"Germany"},{continent:"Asia", Country:"Rassia"},{continent:"NAmerica", Country:"Canada"}];   
    var answer = arrayMap.reduce(function(continent,Country){
        return continent[Country.continent] = (continent[Country.continent] || 0) + 1, continent }, {});
    console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello,

Check if this is what you need:

Code Example:

```
var obj = { };
for (var i = 0, j = arrayMap.length; i < j; i++) {
   obj[arrayMap[i].continent] = (obj[arrayMap[i].continent] || 0) + 1;  
}
console.log(obj);
```

Result:

```
Object {Asia: 4, NAmerica: 2, Australia: 1, Europe: 2, SAmerica: 1}
```

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
let groupByContinent = {}
arrayMap.map(data => {
   if(groupByContinent[data.continent])
      groupByContinent[data.continent] += 1
   else
     groupByContinent[data.continent] = 1
})
console.log(groupByContinent)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in an ExtJS store with grouping on continent, you can use [`store.count(true)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-count).

Otherwise, I don't know any builtin function - you may have to loop over your array and count the continent values yourself.